# JQuery slide doesn't seem to be smooth?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe because my PC is quite old and slow, but JQuery's slide seems to not be very smooth. It's fine if there are not many elements on the page, but becomes sluggish even after embedding one youtube video.

My code is very simple

```
$('#mainmenu-cats').click(function(){

    $('#main-categories').slideToggle(400, 'swing');

    return false;
});
```

Is there any way to make JQuery smoother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: jQuery's animations just aren't as smooth as, say, MooTools'. There is nothing wrong with your code, and in some browsers (Firefox is notorious for it) the animation will just be jerky.

One future-looking solution would be to start looking into replacing these animations with CSS Animations. They're hardware-accelerated in many cases and will provide a smoother experience. Then, you can fallback to jQuery animations if the browser doesn't support animation (you can use Modernizr to detect this).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. CSS animations are a great thing to start learning now, but as IE always has to catch up, I would wait. I have heard of MooTools but never used it. Have you ever used it before? How does it compare to jquery?

Comment: MooTools and jQuery are different beasts, with somewhat different goals. If your foremost concern is smooth animation, I'd say it's something to look into. But, jQuery is used on far, far more sites.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I'll at least check out MooTools